# iOS multi-threading response

Tags: ios, multithreading, httpresponse

I have an app that requires data from a web server. I have servers in different countries in order to ensure fast response for local request. At the start of the app I would like to decide which server I should use, so my plan is to send a request to different servers and check which responses first.

I have a `check.php` on each server and return "ok" as response, and I'm able to call it in different threads, but I have no idea how to set `serverURL` to the server that first response. Can anyone help? Or is there a better way to achieve what I want?

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://server_de/check.php"];
NSError *e = nil;
NSString* result = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:url encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&e];
if (result == nil || ![result isEqualToString:@"ok"]) {
    serverURL=ServerDE;
}
```

EDIT: all servers will respond, but the ones on the other side of the world will be slower. I need to set the fastest server, not the slowest one.

Comment: make a flag variable for each server, linked with your url vars.

Comment: dispatch the `url` to the main thread using GCD, set `serverURL` if it is not nil.

Comment: @KudoCC, could you provide a bit more detail?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say you sent a number of requests and every request overrides your `serverURL` value when it's finished, that's why you get the latest one in the end. To avoid that you could make `serverURL` as a property or global variable and then check if `serverURL` has already value before the assignment and if it has, then do not update it.

```
if ((result == nil || ![result isEqualToString:@"ok"]) && serverURL != nil) {
    serverURL = aServer;
}
```

Actually as soon as you get the first response you can cancel other request because you don't need their answers anymore.

Comment: i think the (result == nil || ![result isEqualToString:@"ok"])  part is just the fallback part but your answer is correct.

Comment: `serverURL` is global value in multiple threads, so you should employ some synchronization tools for example lock or dispatch the judgment and assignment to main thread.